# Sharing data between different devices with phonegap/cordova

Tags: iphone, cordova, ipad, bluetooth, wifi-direct

I've developed an iPad app to use for slotracing setups. That app receives data from the track using a bluetooth connection. As a next step, I'd like to create another app for phones (multi platform, iOS first) which can be used as a "driver display" for each driver. While the iPad is the "master", the phones should be able to act as "slaves" which connect to the master and receive data for the chosen driver (such as race position, best time, etc.).

I was thinking about using wifi direct for this matter, but I don't think there is wifi direct support in cordova/phonegap which I'm using for development of the app(s).

Are there any other possibilities to establish such a connection between different devices?

Thanks for every hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which will probably work for me. I'm using cordova plugins to have a websocket connection between master and slaves. I'm not finished implementing this, but built a proof of concept which seems to work pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

In this app, do you have internet connection access? If so, you can try web service. Provide a way of storing data from your master device and then access it from the slave ones.

Build a way to provide data through URLs, your app can request from a database for example.

I hope that gives you an idea to solve your problem.